# I am getting NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID when try to record script from JMeter

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I setup the same proxy setting in my browser setting as in the JMeter. I tried to record some other website with same settings and they recorded successfully.

Following is the screenshot of the which I am getting. Any help in this regard really appreciated.

Error: net::err_cert_authority_invalid

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Disable Chrome Certificate Checks](https://support.opendns.com/hc/en-us/articles/227989087-Chrome-for-Windows-only-HSTS-Certificate-Exception-Instructions) (Windows Only)

To force Chrome to ignore these errors, you'll need to set your shortcut for Chrome to launch the application with the following switch:

```
--ignore-certificate-errors
```

> Note that Google may choose to remove this feature at any time and thus it is only recommended as long as it is available

To add this command line flag to Chrome, right-click the Chrome icon shortcut, select "Properties" and add it to the Target as shown below:

[image]

Comment: appreciate your answer. I tried this solution but it didn't work for me. Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

The "NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID" error message usually occurs in a web browser when there is a problem with the SSL certificate of the website being accessed.

In your case, the website you are trying to record a script from using JMeter is returning an SSL certificate that is not trusted by the browser.

To resolve this issue, you can try these steps:

1 Check the website's SSL certificate: Make sure the website has a valid SSL certificate, and it has been issued by a trusted certificate authority.

2 Bypass SSL certificate validation: If the website's SSL certificate is not valid, you can bypass SSL certificate validation in JMeter. This can be done by adding the following line to the system.properties file in the JMeter installation directory:

```
javax.net.ssl.trustStore=NUL
```

3 Use a trusted proxy: If you are using a proxy server to record scripts in JMeter, make sure the proxy server is trusted and has a valid SSL certificate.

If the above steps do not resolve the issue, you can try recording the script using a different browser or a different machine.